# uninstalling on linux

Tags: linux, installation

I'm new to compiling and installing programs on linux. I understand the common process is to do
`./configure`

`make`

`make install`

I'd like to know if there is some way I can "rollback" if I make a mistake somewhere or if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agree with other answers, and I wanted to clarify a bit. If my understanding is correct, typically `./configure` is a script that makes sure / sets up your system so that compilation will go correctly. Then `make` runs a Makefile that actually compiles. Then `make install` runs the makefile with `install` as a parameter that actually copies your binaries and config files to the appropriate (as determined by the script author) system directories, which is why often `make install` must be run with elevated privileges.

Often the make script takes an `uninstall` parameter that actually erases everything that was copied to system directories. In my experience, this isn't always going to be a clean process. There's no fireproof way to roll back without ensuring yourself that all changes are tracked perfectly and writing the rollback script yourself.

In short, try `make uninstall` and if that doesn't work and you can't figure it out yourself, try posting on a mailing list or forum pertaining to the particular product in question.

Edit for more info:
just running `make` should get you everything you need to run a program, as long as you keep your working directory as wherever you ran `make` from. That is, `make` will create all your binaries and config files, etc, and you can use the software fine from that directory. You won't have any globally accessible binaries or proper environment variables, though, if you don't copy things to system directories, such as with `make install`. So if you're just trying to run a self-contained binary that isn't software that something else will rely on, you don't actually need to run `make install` and won't have to worry about rolling back. Everything will be contained within your original working directory.

Answer (score 2):

If `make unistall` does not make the trick then you have to remove the files on your own (except if there is an unistall script.

One good way to avoid all the mess is to use the `checkinstall` after installing something from source. This way it will create also a package file for your system meaning that you will be able to unistall the software from the package manager e.g. `apt-get remove my_software`.

Comment: I have had bad experience with attempting to use automatic distro-appropriate packages (OpenSUSE, Ubuntu)

Comment: As @che said, yes it works only for Slackware, RPM or Debian compatible packages.

Comment: @che: there are programs whose names escape me at the moment [not on linux box] that attempt to automatically create a package suitable for your distro, given a binary or config files perhaps. It's been at least six months since I used these, but frequently when I attempted to use them, they created RPMs or DEBs that failed to install properly with errors in the scripts, or IIRC sometimes the binaries they installed failed to run, with failed .so dependencies (which the package manager should have caught) or incompatible dependency library versions. Based on memory, it was things like that.

Comment: @taz: Those generated packages may not contain all the proper dependency information, so it's likely they'll fail when trasferred to another system. If this happenned on the same system you've built them, it's kind of weird but I guess such things may happen.

Comment: @che: Yes, I don't recall trying to transfer systems. I have had experiences where the generated packages did work, but I've also had experiences where they didn't. I like the idea, I just don't consider them super-reliable. Also I don't have a lot of knowledge or experience with these, just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1):

Check if Makefile script has

```
make uninstall
```

target. It is not unusual to find these.

Otherwise, you might need to check where stuff gets installed and have your own backout script.

Answer (score 0):

typically `./configure` takes in various parameters.

So lets say you did a `make` and `make install` and then realized that you want to reconfigure your software, you will have to first uninstall it using `uninstall` scripts that the software provides.

`make uninstall` may also work.