# How do I completely uninstall git from my Linux Machine

Tags: linux, git, bash, github, git-svn

I had installed git by downloading the tar ball and then doing the following steps

```
./configure --prefix=/scratch/custom/git

make 

make install
```

But after running these commands, I still see that git is created under `/usr/local` as below

```
bash-4.1$ whereis git
git: /usr/bin/git /usr/local/git /usr/share/man/man1/git.1.gz
```

I would like to remove and reinstall again how do i do the same?

Comment: possible duplicate of [uninstalling on linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803506/uninstalling-on-linux)

Comment: Sometimes there are good reasons to install git from source (say, if you want a newer version than the default), but usually just installing it with a package management system is sufficient. For Debian/Ubuntu/etc., `sudo apt-get install git`. For Red Hat-based systems, use some `rpm` command that I don't remember.

Comment: @KeithThompson, on recent Fedora / CentOS / RHEL systems you would use `yum`.

Answer (score 4):

If `make unistall` doesn't work, as mentioned here, [uninstalling on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803506/uninstalling-on-linux), try `make install` again, capturing the output.

Then go through all of the install commands and manually remove the installed files.

Also, 'make -n` may help to determine all of the installed files.