# How to let git use https when clone repository?

Tags: git, https, centos, rhel, rhel7

Installed this package on OS

```
yum install curl-devel
```

Installed git by source

```
wget https://github.com/git/git/archive/v2.26.2.tar.gz
tar zxvf v2.26.2.tar.gz
cd git-2.26.2
make configure
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
make install
```

Version

```
git --version
git version 2.26.2
```

Clone repo with https

```
git clone https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher.git
Cloning into 'the_silver_searcher'...
fatal: unable to find remote helper for 'https'
```

Why? If this way doesn't work, how to uninstall git now?

Comment: It is weird that you not asked to enter your github username and password as described here - https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/which-remote-url-should-i-use
What is the outcome when you try to clone with SSH instead of HTTPS? p.s. to clone with SSH, you first need to add SSH key to your machine and Github account..

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Unable to find remote helper for 'https'" during git clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329485/unable-to-find-remote-helper-for-https-during-git-clone)

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari Actually I have tried that. But still not work. On RHEL 7.6

Comment: *how to uninstall git now?* : See [How do I completely uninstall git from my Linux Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27324652/10155936) , also apart from installing from source try installing `git` using `yum`

Comment: In addition to that, you can also find the path where `git` core programs are installed using `git --exec-path` and check if `git-remote-https` exists in that path

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari Thank you. I checked it. It there: `ls /usr/libexec/git-core | grep https`. Returned `git-remote-https`.

Comment: Run the git clone command after running this `export GIT_EXEC_PATH=/usr/libexec/git-core` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52816804/10155936)

Comment: Consider adding `/usr/libexec/git-core` to the `PATH` env variable so you don't have to run `export GIT_EXEC_PATH=/usr/libexec/git-core` each time you open a new session (in the terminal)